# How do I make a Ruby method that makes a diamond of asterisks with 'n' width?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, methods, drawing, newline

I'm trying to make a method that returns a string that looks like a diamond shape when printed on the screen, using asterisk **(*)** characters. I want to remove any trailing characters and each line to be **terminated** with a **(\n)**. I also want it to return **nil** if the input is an even number or negative, as it is not possible to print a diamond of even or negative size. For example

```
       *
n=3   ***
       * 

        *
       ***
n=5   *****
       ***
        *
```

or in other words

```
"  *\n ***\n*****\n ***\n  *\n"
```

Method looking something like this:

```
def diamond(n)
  
end
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Counting 1, 3, 5, 3, 1? Printing _n_ asterisks? Centering them? Or maybe the error handling? What is it and what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
def diamond(n)
  return nil if n.even? || n.negative?
  
  diamond_string = ""
  n.times do |i|
    space_count = (i - n / 2).abs
    asterisk_count = n - space_count * 2
    diamond_string << [' ' * space_count, '*' * asterisk_count].join + "\n"
  end

  return diamond_string
end
```

Comment: why do you care if number is negative?

Comment: you don't need to use times with a block when you can simply do `diamond_string << '*' * space_count` which is simpler and more readable IMHO.

Comment: I personally don't (this method would yield the same result as the the absolute value of n if a negative number is passed). However, the question stated that it should return nil if the input is even or negative. Good point with the shovel operator, will update accordingly.

Comment: even simpler `diamond_string << [' ' * space_count, '*' * asterisk_count].join + "\n"` and `index` is really `iteration` because it's not an array, though `i` would suffice.

Comment: Updated with suggested changes

Comment: I'll upvote if you omit the old version.  Unless the question changed, no need for your refactor history.

Comment: Removed original implementation

Comment: in ruby, explicit `return` is not needed unless you are doing an early return. The last command in the method always returns it's value so just `diamond_string` is preferred as per [ruby style guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-explicit-return)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```rb
def diamond(n)
  return nil if n < 1 || n.even?

  odds = (1..n).select(&:odd?)
  (odds + odds[0..-2].reverse).map { |i| ('*' * i).center(n).chomp << "\n" }.join
end
```

Comment: I just follow the requirement: `I also want it to return nil if the input is an even number or negative`.

Comment: The only problem is there needs to be a newline (\n) after every asterisk, yours works for all but the last one.

Comment: Updated it based on your comment.